# ArgumentOutOfRangeException in protobuf-net

Tags: protobuf-net

i have the following code

```
<ProtoContract()> _
Public Class CtMsg

Public Sub New()
End Sub

 <ProtoMember(1)> _
 Public Property MessageType As MessageType = MessageType.mtMessage

End Class

  <ProtoContract()> _
Public Enum MessageType
    mtLogin = 4
    mtAuthenticated = 1
    mtHello = 2
    mtLogout = 3
    mtMessage = 0
End Enum
```

The  class CtMsg is Serialize fine  on the client but on the server it gives the below error

the data sent from client matches exactly byte by byte on the server 
but during the Deserialize it gives the below error

what can be causing the error ?

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException occurred
Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: tag
Source=protobuf-net
ParamName=tag
StackTrace:
at ProtoBuf.ProtoMemberAttribute..ctor(Int32 tag, Boolean forced) in 
 K:\softwares\protobuf-net r278\src\protobuf-net\ProtoMemberAttribute.cs:line 45
 InnerException:
```

---

I have tried the v2 , i got the same exact error 
but when i change my project and related references to debug the exact same code work with any issue

but for release version it gives the error , still have to find why it is not working in release version and will post my findings

Thanks

Comment: I've just returned from a few days away. I I'll look at this later

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this; are the client and server using matching contracts? i.e. are you *sure* it looks the same as the above on both? It may also be worth seeing if simply using "v2" fixes the issue.

Comment: ok i will try with v2 , in the above code the enum MessageType have 13 enums in it and class CtMsg also have 13 properties , may be that is the problem , the contracts are in separate dll and this same dll is used between both client and server

Comment: the "same dll" usually solves all problems (it is the simplest and most robust setup), so I am genuinely surprised by the issue. Simply: I have never seen this before so without more details it is very hard to repro. Do you have more stacktrace I could look at? Or anything else I can use to reproduce it?

Comment: do you have v2 dll for just .net 2  as whole project is .net 2 and cannot upgrade it to v3  and above

Comment: yes. There is a 2.0 build and a 3.0 build if you want WCF. My last deploy was probably 3.0, but both source and the previous builds will have all variants. If you really need it but can't build from source, email me and I'll send you an up-to-date 2.0. Actually, I even back ported to 1.1 if you want support for crazy-old code :)

Comment: yes please send me the 2 build of v2